# AutoFill OTP is not working after received authentication code from firebase am using sms_Auto_fill package here is my code

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms_autofill/sms_autofill.dart';
import 'package:FirebasePractice/Ui/posts/post_screen.dart';
import 'package:FirebasePractice/Utils/Utils.dart';
import 'package:FirebasePractice/widgets/roundbutton.dart';

class VerifyCode extends StatefulWidget {
  final String verificationId;

  const VerifyCode({Key? key, required this.verificationId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VerifyCode> createState() => _VerifyCodeState();
}

class _VerifyCodeState extends State<VerifyCode> {
  bool loading = false;
  final verifyCodeController = TextEditingController();
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listenForCode();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    TextEditingController().dispose();
    SmsAutoFill().unregisterListener();
  }

  _listenForCode() async {
    await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode();
    print("OTP listen Called");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Verify"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            PinFieldAutoFill(
              currentCode: "",
              codeLength: 6,
              autoFocus: true,
              controller: verifyCodeController,
              onCodeSubmitted: (code){
                print("onCodeChanged $code");
              },
              onCodeChanged: (val){
                print("onCodeChanged $val");
              },
              decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                colorBuilder: const FixedColorBuilder(Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            Roundbutton(
              title: "Verify",
              loading: loading,
              onTap: () async {
                setState(() {
                  loading = true;
                });
                final credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                  verificationId: widget.verificationId,
                  smsCode: verifyCodeController.text.toString(),
                );
                try {
                  await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Postscreen()),
                  );
                } catch (e) {
                  setState(() {
                    loading = false; // Corrected: Set loading to false when an error occurs
                  });
                  Utils().toastmessage(e.toString());
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AutoFill OTP is not working after received authentication code from firebase  am using sms_Auto_fill package  here is my code am using firebase, sms auto fill  and firebase authentication code, when received a verification code from firebase then i have to fill it manually instead of auto filled by the my code

Comment: `androidSmsAutofillMethod:  AndroidSmsAutofillMethod.smsUserConsentApi,`

with giving necessity  permission it kinda work for me without using any package.

(If You getting the top via SMS only)

Comment: `Pinput(
                autofocus: true,
                androidSmsAutofillMethod:  AndroidSmsAutofillMethod.smsUserConsentApi,
                autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.oneTimeCode],
                length: 6,
                defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  pinCode = value;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                validator: (s) {
                  return s!.length == 6 ? null : 'Pin is incorrect';
                },
              ),`